# NullReferenceException c# in controller

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I get a `NullReferenceException` when try to run a view.
I don't see the code that cause this problem.
Can someone explain the problem? thanks

This is the Model class:

```
public class Catalogus: ICatalogus
{
    private readonly DbSet<Materiaal> materialen;
    private IEnumerable<Materiaal> materialenTest;
    private Firma firma;

    public Catalogus()
    {
        firma = new Firma("hh", "lol@gmail.com");
        materialenTest = new Materiaal[] { new Materiaal(5, 0, "1", "test", "test", "ts", firma, "wereldbol", "wereldbol", "lol", 0, true) };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Materiaal> VindAlleMaterialen()
    {
        return materialenTest.OrderBy(m => m.Naam);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Materiaal> ZoekOpTrefwoord(string trefwoord)
    {
        IEnumerable<Materiaal> gefilterdMaterialen = materialenTest.Where(mat => mat.GetType().GetProperty("naam").GetValue(this).Equals(trefwoord));

        return gefilterdMaterialen;
    }
}
```

The controller with the NullRef exception:

This line cause the problem.

> IEnumerable materialen = catalogus.VindAlleMaterialen().OrderBy(m => m.Naam).ToList();

```
public class CatalogusController : Controller
{
    private ICatalogus catalogus;

    public CatalogusController() { }

    public CatalogusController(ICatalogus catalogus)
    {
        this.catalogus = catalogus;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Materiaal> materialen = catalogus.VindAlleMaterialen().OrderBy(m => m.Naam).ToList();

        return View(materialen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like either it calls the default constructor not injecting catalogus, or one of the elements is null or has a null `Naam`.

Comment: Having a controller with interface parameters in the constructor tells me you're probably using some kind of DI framework, maybe Ninject - in that scenario, there's something wrong with your setup. Maybe just remove the default constructor and see if that works, and if not, consult your documentation on your DI framework to ensure that it's configured properly.

Comment: where is this line *IEnumerable materialen = catalogus.VindAlleMaterialen().OrderBy(m => m.Naam).ToList();*  in the code posted above???

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa 4th row from the end, although it has a template parameter that was missing in the text.

Answer (score 7):

Your default constructor `public CatalogusController` does not create an `catalogus` instance. When you then execute `catalogus.VindAlleMaterialen().OrderBy(m => m.Naam).ToList();` it results in a NullReferenceException because `catalogus` is null.

If your overloaded constructor IS being called (probably not the case) you should validate the incoming parameter.

```
public CatalogusController(ICatalogus catalogus)
{
    if(catalogus == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("catalogus");
    this.catalogus = catalogus;
}
```

Comment: Without the default constructor I receive "MissingMethodException". says I don"t have a parameterles constructor. that's the reason I try to add the default constructor.

Comment: @Dave_888 - This means you are probably using a DI (dependency injection) or IoC framework. You probably did not register your `Catalogus` with it and specify that `ICatalogus` instances can be replaced with that type. If you want more help on that you should include that information (what DI framework and the registration code).

Comment: @Dave_888 - if this is not the case then you should create a new instance of `catalogus` in the default constructor and assign it to your private field `catalogus`. How ever you look at it, if your `catalogus` instance is null you will get a `NullReferenceException` as soon as you try to access it's properties/methods.

Comment: oke,thx for your comments. I will ask if I need further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone could contruct a CatalogusController without passing in an ICatalogus object.  This will cause a NullReferenceException when someone calls `controller.Index()`:

```
// Create a controller object using the default constructor
CatalogusController controller = new CatalogusController();

// this causes a NullReferenceException because controller.catalogus is null
controller.Index();
```